# Lato font rendering error

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts

I've come across a strange issue with the Lato font. It seems to be rendering very strangely, but only when you're zoomed in close or if the font is large.

Here is a screenshot of the font in illustrator when zoomed out

[image]

And here i have zoomed in to 100%

[image]

If i enter outline view using Command+Y, the error isn't there

[image]

Unless of course i Create Outlines (Shift+Command+O)

[image]

I've re downloaded the font and I'm still getting the same issue. Seems to be an adobe issue as I'm having no trouble with the font in Word for example.

Might be a long shot but I'd like to know if anyone has come across anything similar, and if so what did you do?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this font freely available, so we can see for ourselves, or is it commercial (and  if so, do you have a license)?

Comment: @RadLexus Lato is a pretty nice font that you can download from google fonts. So yes, it's free. I have it, I use it and NEVER encountered this, even now while doing the same thing as the OP.

Comment: so what happens if you zoom out and create outlines? or maybe use a bigger font size?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what zoom level i'm at, the error still occurs _after_ outlining. The only time the error does not _display_ is _before_ outlining and when i'm zoomed out beyond 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue and when I investigated my fonts it notes that the version I had installed was for web only. I found a desktop version of the font and now I can convert the text to outlines without any issues. I hope this helps

Here is a link to where I downloaded the font. http://www.latofonts.com/